# How to pipe ap calls after using getApplicativeValidation on an Either in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, applicative, fp-ts

Yesterday me and a few colleagues were trying to get a toy example for applicative validation in fp-ts to work. We finally got it working with manually storing each interim step in a variable and calling the next step. But it would be way more elegant using the pipe function from fp-ts. Doing it with Either directly works, but does not combine multiple Left values into one (e.g. concatenating arrays with string errors).
But with pipe() the ap()-calls want two arguments, but only get one. How do we use pipe correctly here:

```
import * as E from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import * as RA from "fp-ts/lib/ReadonlyArray";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

export class CreditCard {
    constructor(
        public readonly number: string,
        public readonly expiry: string,
        public readonly cvv: string
    ) { }
}

export const validate = (
    card: CreditCard
): E.Either<ReadonlyArray<string>, CreditCard> => {
    const createCreditCard = (a: string) => (b: string) => (c: string) =>
        new CreditCard(a, b, c);

    const v1 = (s: string): E.Either<ReadonlyArray<string>, string> => {
        return s !== "invalid" ? E.right(s) : E.left(RA.of("invalid number"));
    };

    const v2 = (s: string): E.Either<ReadonlyArray<string>, string> => {
        return s !== "invalid" ? E.right(s) : E.left(RA.of("invalid expiry"));
    };

    const v3 = (s: string): E.Either<ReadonlyArray<string>, string> => {
        return s !== "invalid" ? E.right(s) : E.left(RA.of("invalid cvv"));
    };

    const V = E.getApplicativeValidation((RA.getSemigroup<string>()));

    // this does not work, because V.ap wants 2 arguments but only has 1?
    // const fromPipe = pipe(
    //     V.of(createCreditCard),
    //     V.ap(v1(card.number)),
    //     V.ap(v2(card.expiry)),
    //     V.ap(v3(card.cvv))
    // );
    // return fromPipe;

    // this works, but is ugly
    const liftedFunction = V.of(createCreditCard);
    const afterFirstValidation = V.ap(liftedFunction, v1(card.number));
    const afterSecondValidation = V.ap(afterFirstValidation, v2(card.expiry));
    const afterThirdValidation = V.ap(afterSecondValidation, v3(card.cvv));

    return afterThirdValidation;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Either.getApplicativeValidation` returns an instance of `Applicative2C` which has non-pipeable versions of the class methods. Currently, the way you get pipeable versions of instances computed with combinators (like `getApplicativeValidation`) is to pass the instance to the `pipeable` combinator from the `pipeable.ts` module.

So change your code to this:

```
const validation = E.getApplicativeValidation(RA.getSemigroup<string>())
const V = pipeable(validation)

const fromPipe = pipe(
  validation.of(createCreditCard),
  V.ap(v1(card.number)),
  V.ap(v2(card.expiry)),
  V.ap(v3(card.cvv))
)
```

And you should find it works as you wanted.

However, I believe in `fp-ts` v3.x.x, type class interfaces will be changed to all be pipeable by default, so the need for `pipeable` will go away then.